# RODBC package: How to get a logical value for the "Does the Table Exists?" query type?

Tags: sql, r, rodbc

I am trying to transform the R/Shiny/SQL application to use data from SQL Server instead of Oracle. In the original code there is a lot of the following type conditions: If the table exists, use it as a data set, otherwise upload new data. I was looking for a counterpart of `dbExistsTable` command from `DBI/ROracle` packages, but the `odbcTableExists` is unfortunately just internal `RODBC` command not usable in `R` environment. Also a wrapper for `RODBC` package, allowing to use `DBI` type commands - `RODBCDBI` seems not working. Any ideas? 
Here is some code example:

```
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCDBI)

con <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL
    Server};server=xx.xx.xx.xxx;database=test;uid=user;pwd=pass123')

odbcTableExists(con, "table")
```

Error: could not find function "odbcTableExists"

```
dbExistsTable(con,"table")
```

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbExistsTable’ for signature ‘"RODBC", "character"’

Comment: Have you tried calling it with `:::`, i.e. `RODBC:::odbcTableExists(con, "table")`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was not aware of such a possibility, still a newbie to many R functionalities. The output of your suggestion is `[1] "\"table\""`. If I intentionally use a non-existing table, there is an error message. With some wrap it can be hopefully used in an if statement.

Comment: @Benjamin's answer is probably more idiomatic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use

```
[Table] %in% sqlTables(conn)$TABLE_NAME
```

Where `[Table]` is a character string of the table you are looking for.